# Mouse disables on key press, but touchpad doesn't

Tags: keyboard, mouse

My mouse cursor disables for 1-2 seconds when the keyboard is used. This can make gaming especially difficult. The touchpad is fine; I can use it at the same time as the keyboard. Doing some forum searching, I can see that going to mouse and touchpad > touchpad > disable touchpad when typing works for the touchpad, but I still have the problem when using the mouse. I've tried using synaptiks, and setting the 'automatically switch off touchpad on keyboard activity' time to 0 seconds doesn't seem to work either.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your mouse is behaving as a touchpad and vice versa. Quite strange.

Anyway try opening Mouse and Touchpad and under the touchpad tab, deselect "disable touchpad while typing". If, as I suspect, somehow your system is switching mouse and touchpad, this should solve your problem.